Evaluating $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{2^{x^x}+x-3}{x-1}$ without L'Hopital's rule
I want to evaluate $\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{2^{x^x}+x-3}{x-1}$. I used L'Hopital's:
$$\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{2^{x^x}+x-3}{x-1}= \lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{(x^x)'(\ln(2)\times 2^{x^x})+1}1$$
Let $y=x^x$,
$$\ln y=x\ln x\Rightarrow \dfrac{y'}y=\ln (x)+1\Rightarrow (x^x)'=x^x(1+\ln x)$$
Overall, the limit is equivalent to to $\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{(x^x)(1+\ln x)(\ln(2)\times 2^{x^x})+1}1=1+2\ln2= \ln(4e)$.
I'm wondering if we can calculate this limit without applying the L'Hopital's rule.

Hint: $x-3=x-1- 2$

@SineoftheTime Ok we have $1+\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{2^{x^x}-2}{x-1}$ and the limit is equivalent to definition of derivative of $y=2^{x^x}$  at $x=1$. Is this what you meant?

Yes, that's what I meant!

We have that
$$\dfrac{2^{x^x}+x-3}{x-1}=1+\dfrac{2^{x^x}-2}{x-1}\to 1+\ln 4$$
indeed by standard limits
$$\dfrac{2^{x^x}-2}{x-1}=2\ln 2\dfrac{e^{((x^x-1)\ln 2)}-1}{(x^x-1)\ln 2}\frac{e^{x\ln x}-1}{x\ln x}\frac{x\ln x}{x-1} \to \ln 4 \cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1 =\ln 4 $$

Nice use of standard limits. I was going to post a similar answer but then saw yours and stopped. +1

@ParamanandSingh Really sorry for that! Thanks for your appreciation. Bye

@user Thanks for the answer. Can you please elaborate on the standard limits that you have used?

@user1380196 Essentially we have only used $\frac{e^t-1}{t}\to 1$ as $t\to 0$.

@user1380196 For the latter by $t=x-1 \to 0$ we have $$\frac{x\ln x}{x-1} = \frac{(t+1)\ln (1+t)}{t} \to 1$$ which is equivalent to the previous one.

@user Thanks a lot I understood it.

@user1380196 If the answer satisfies you, you can accept it

I'm putting my comment in an answer for the sake of completeness. Rewrite $x-3$ as $x-1-2$ to get:
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{2^{x^x}+x-1-2}{x-1}=1+\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{2^{x^x}-2}{x-1}=1+\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=1+f'(1) $$
where $f(x)=2^{x^x}$.

This is also a very fine method!

@user Thank you. Actually, I think our answers are equivalent since fundamental limits are derivative of some functions at the end of the day :)

Yes they are strictly related even if standard limits are usually discussed and obtained before to introduce derivative concept.

@user absolutely, since you use them to find the derivatives of the elementary functions

I am agree with the @user comment.
